# Autostart in Realme 2 Pro

Tags: android, autostart

I am working on an app where i need to keep a service running always and for that i am taking the "Autostart" permission from the user and once that is granted from the user i am able to keep my service alive even after the app is closed from the task manager. Now the problem is that when i am redirecting user to the "Autostart" permission settings page, its getting redirected on that "Autostart" or "Battery Optimization" settings page in almost all devices except **Realme 2 Pro**. I am using the below mentioned code to take user to the "Battery Optimization" settings page.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

But in case of Realme 2 pro, it's taking the user to the app settings page and there i can see 2 options "Allow Autostart" and "Power Saver". I am not sure which option do i need to turn on to keep my service alive.
I am attaching the screenshot of the settings dialog that is being opened.

[image]

Comment: r u find any solutions about this problem , i am facing same problem here can you help me.

Comment: "Allow Autostart" and "Power Saver", try turning on both the options, it's working in my case.

Comment: Thank you replying , i tried both but still not working foreground services , alarm manager , work manager , can you please share code about background services.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Allow Autostart option worked for me to allow PeriodWorker in Realme